# How to use post method with Facebook graph API in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use C# to make friend with uid=14650247412 base on graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/14650247412?access_token=EAAAxxx&method=post
```

But I don't know how to implement in C#, could you please help me do it?

I'm using Facebook from Nudget package

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
string uid = "14650247412";

dynamic parameters = {};
client.AccessToken = "EAAxxx";
var result = client.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/" + uid , parameters);
```

the result is empty data

```
data = {}
```

Could you please show me how to do it? Thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

No. Adding friends is not possible through the API.

However, you can direct users to the webpage `http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=[USER UID]`

Where `[USER UID]` is a valid facebook user id.

Use `WebBrowser` control in a form dialog to achieve this.

Comment: Dear Christlin Panner, How about request like fanpage? is not possible through the API too?

Comment: use the lik button plugin for that

Comment: @Zidane you can achieve like using the API. Visit for the reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/likes

Comment: @ChristlinPanneer Thanks!, I know achieve like using that api, but my question's "I have one fanpage? may I use graph api to invite people like my fanpage?" and the same, "if I have group? may I use graph api to invite any people join my group"? Thanks

Comment: I think it is not available

Comment: Your question is now out of context (Based on your comment)